# Is it ok by code to enclose a residentail breaker box in a finished basement as long as there is an access door and what are the requirements?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, breaker-box

I am finishing a basement and want to enclose the 200a service box and wiring with a framed cabinet of some sort.  Is there any requirements for clearances and what you can enclose it with?  I am in PA.
Thx!

Comment: Related: [What is permissible for a breaker box cover?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/11499/2196) and [Is it code-legal to have a circuit breaker box within a storage room?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/25917/2196)

Comment: Also, beyond NEC, is it a fire code violation? Your local Fire Marshall will be another person who can tell you what passes fire inspection. They get really interested in obstructions and obscuring of locations for this kind of equipment. If the fireman cannot walk directly to, identify and access the panel, you will fail the fire inspection.